# Issues with Dynamic Dropdowns in ASP.NET Core 6 Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on a project using ASP.NET Core where I have dynamic dropdowns for subjects and students in a Razor view. The goal is to filter students based on the selected subject, but I am encountering issues.

Razor View:

```
@model SolutionName.Models.ViewBagStudentSubject

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Exam</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            @* Display SubjectCode as a hidden field since it's part of the composite key *@
            <input asp-for="SubjectCode" type="hidden" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.SubjectCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Exam.SubjectCode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Subjects"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StudentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Students"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var subjects = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Subjects)) || [];
    var studentsForSubject = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Students)) || [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var subjectSelect = $("#Exam_SubjectCode");
        var studentSelect = $("#StudentId");

        subjectSelect.on("change", function () {
            var selectedSubjectCode = $(this).val();

            studentSelect.empty();
            studentSelect.append($('<option>', {
                value: "",
                text: "Select a student",
                class: "text-muted",
                disabled: true,
                selected: true
            }));

            if (subjects && subjects.length > 0 && selectedSubjectCode) {
                // Find the selected subject
                var selectedSubject = subjects.find(function (subject) {
                    return subject.Value === selectedSubjectCode;
                });

                // Filter students based on the selected subject's code and class
                var filteredStudents = studentsForSubject.filter(function (student) {
                    return student.SubjectCode === selectedSubjectCode && student.Subject.Class === selectedSubject.Class;
                });

                // Populate students based on the selected subject
                if (filteredStudents && filteredStudents.length > 0) {
                    filteredStudents.forEach(function (student) {
                        studentSelect.append($('<option>', {
                            value: student.StudentId,
                            text: student.Student.FullName
                        }));
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        subjectSelect.trigger("change");
    });
</script>
```

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Create()
 {
     Exam exam = new();

     ViewData["SubjectCode"] = new SelectList(_context.Subjects, "SubjectCode", "SubjectCode");
     ViewBag.Subjects = _context.Subjects.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.SubjectCode.ToString(), Text = s.NameOfSubject }).ToList();

     // Get the selected subject code from the exam object
     var selectedSubjectCode = exam.SubjectCode;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSubjectCode))
     {
         var selectedSubject = _context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubjectCode == selectedSubjectCode);

         if (selectedSubject != null)
         {
             var subjectClass = selectedSubject.Class;

             // Create a list of ViewBagStudentSubject objects
             var studentSubjectMappings = _context.Students
                 .Where(s => s.Class == subjectClass)
                 .Select(s => new ViewBagStudentSubject
                 {
                     StudentId = s.StudentId,
                     SubjectCode = selectedSubjectCode,
                     Student = s,
                     Subject = selectedSubject,
                     Exam = exam // Pass the exam object to ViewBagStudentSubject
                 })
                 .ToList();

             ViewBag.Students = studentSubjectMappings
                 .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StudentId.ToString(), Text = s.Student.FullName })
                 .ToList();
         }
     }

     // Pass the entire ViewBagStudentSubject object to the view
     ViewBag.ViewBagStudentSubject = new ViewBagStudentSubject
     {
         Exam = exam,
         Students = ViewBag.Students
     };

     return View();
 }
```

ViewBagStudentSubject model:

```
public class ViewBagStudentSubject
 {
     [Key]
     public int StudentId { get; set; }
     [Key]
     [MaxLength(3)]
     public string SubjectCode { get; set; }

     public Student Student { get; set; }
     public Subject Subject { get; set; }

     public int ExamId;
     public Exam Exam;
     public List<SelectListItem> Students { get; set; }
 }
```

The issue I am facing is that the students dropdown doesn't update when I change the selected subject. I have verified that the data in ViewBag.Students is correct, and there are no errors in the browser console.

Expected Behavior:

When I select a subject, I expect the students dropdown to dynamically update based on the selected subject.(both student and subject has "Class" property)

Comment: You should use Ajax and Javascript to accomplish that. Your solution require post back and page refresh where the above solution does not require that. It can show the related student as long as the user change the subject dropdown.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?

Comment: @QiangFu I used Ajax in JavaScript and debugging all necessary controllers. Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following codes.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subject
    {
        public string SubjectCode { get; set; }
        public string NameOfSubject { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }
```

VirtualContext.cs

```
    public class VirtualContext
    {
        public List<Subject> Subjects = new List<Subject>()
        {
            new Subject(){SubjectCode="code01",NameOfSubject="Physics",Class="classA"},
            new Subject(){SubjectCode="code02",NameOfSubject="Biology",Class="classB"},
        };

        public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){StudentId=1001,Class="classA",FullName="Tom"},
            new Student(){StudentId=1002,Class="classA",FullName="Kite"},
            new Student(){StudentId=1003,Class="classB",FullName="John"},
            new Student(){StudentId=1004,Class="classB",FullName="Alex"}
        };
    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<VirtualContext>();
```

Controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly VirtualContext _context;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,VirtualContext virtualContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this._context = virtualContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create(string? selectedSubjectCode)
        {

            ViewBag.Subjects = _context.Subjects.Select(s => {
                if (s.SubjectCode == selectedSubjectCode)
                {
                    return new SelectListItem { Value = s.SubjectCode.ToString(), Text = s.NameOfSubject, Selected=true };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new SelectListItem { Value = s.SubjectCode.ToString(), Text = s.NameOfSubject };
                }
            }
            ).ToList();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedSubjectCode))
            {
                var selectedSubject = _context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubjectCode == selectedSubjectCode);
                ViewBag.Students = _context.Students.Where(x=>x.Class==selectedSubject.Class)
                                                    .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StudentId.ToString(), Text = s.FullName })
                                                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Students = _context.Students.Where(x => x.Class == _context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault().Class)
                                    .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StudentId.ToString(), Text = s.FullName })
                                    .ToList();
            }
            
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication11.Models.ViewBagStudentSubject

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Exam</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            @* Display SubjectCode as a hidden field since it's part of the composite key *@
            <input asp-for="SubjectCode" type="hidden" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.SubjectCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Exam.SubjectCode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Subjects" id="subjectcode" onchange="UpdateStudents()" ></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StudentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StudentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Students"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Exam.DateOfExam" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Exam.FinalResult" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<script>
    function UpdateStudents() {
        var selectedSubjectCode = document.getElementById("subjectcode").value;
        window.location.href = "//localhost:7026/home/create?selectedSubjectCode="+selectedSubjectCode;
    }
</script>
```

Test
[image]